# Не отображаются методы в документации Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger

Подключил Swagger к проекту, по мануалу с MSDN, при тестировании в веб проекте все нужные и не нужные методы добавляются в список отображения, исключил не нужные с помощью [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)].

Так же появилась необходимость вынести API в отдельный проект, в том же решении, но документация автоматически не генерируется для методов из другого проекта, как можно прописать путь до проекта или до методов что бы заполнялась документация?

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы решить мою проблему, необходимо было добавить эти библиотеки и все будет работать

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI

Comment: @AK дополнил описание, да, всё заработало. Извиняюсь за неточность